# Chrome extension I'm developing disabled

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I have been working on this extension a while. I just recently tried the trick of getting access to the window inside my background script by injecting a script tag into the page via the content script that sends a message to my extension and I had to add something like this:

```
"externally_connectable": {
  "ids": ["*"],
},
```

to the manifest.json, and as soon as I did, my extension was disabled without any warning or message. Did I do something not allowed? And can I get my extension enabled again? Do I need to delete it and unpack it again? Seems unfortunate if I lose all the data I had in storage.

Comment: I haven't been able to find any link or anything to contact them, their help page is static. If anyone has a link or email (anything) I would love to ask them about this

Comment: It isn't even on the webstore though, they didn't send me any removal email or anything

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand. What is the issue then? The extension is disabled on your browser? can you enable it? Maybe you should edit your question to clarify..

Comment: Yeah sorry, I am developing it on my browser and I can't enable it. I have no idea why though. But it is all faded out

Comment: Even so, I can remove all of that and it doesn't work. it stays disabled and won't reload

Comment: If you're using the redesigned chrome://extensions  page, it may be buggy. Otherwise you probably didn't actually restore manifest.json to the original state.

Comment: Er, I was wrong about *, it's supported in ids. There is probably something else going on. Try https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging